# do category allow addition of instance variables in its implemenation?

Tags: objective-c, io, xcode4.5

I am working ios6.0 sdk with xcode 4.5.2

Here is following code i used to implement a category

.h

```
@interface NSObject (busyMode)  
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL busy;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation NSObject (busyMode)
BOOL _bsy;

-(BOOL)busy{
    return _bsy;
}

-(void)setBusy:(BOOL)busy
{
    _bsy = busy;
}
@end
```

as i read along many post, it says that we cannot have instance variables in category. And so above code should not work. But as i tried it out, all was working fine.

Has there been any changes related to category or was it just luck??

Comment: That isn't an instance variable. Try it with more than one instance of NSObject.

Comment: you were right, not working for two instances. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you didn't add an instance variable, but a global variable which is going to be shared among all of your instances.

Categories cannot add instance variables. However, you can simulate instance variables if you absolutely need them with `objc_setAssociatedObject()` and `objc_getAssociatedObject()`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have defined a single global variable, which isn't an instance variable.

Try and instantiate two instances of this object and you will observe that each instance cannot hold a different value.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added an iVar. You have defined a global variable `_bsy` and are accessing it in the getter/setter for the property defined by your category.

Answer (score 0):

I have a macro that lets you declare "properties" in categories like this:

```
@implementation NSObject (AwesomeUtils)

JESynthesize(assign, NSInteger, index, setIndex);
JESynthesize(strong, NSString *, name, setName);
JESynthesize(copy, void(^)(void), completion, setCompletion);
JESynthesize(unsafe_unretained, id, unsafeObject, setUnsafeObject);
JESynthesize(weak, id<UITableViewDelegate>, delegate, setDelegate);
JESynthesize(strong, NSString *, readonlyID, changeReadonlyID);

// …
@end
```

I say "properties" with quotes because you can use them even without the `@property` declaration. The macro also works around to support `weak`.

You can check the implementation here (the header files are at the bottom):
http://nspicks.com/2013/12/15/cleaner-properties-implementation-in-categories/